# D3 bar chart and html data attributes

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a D3 zoomable bar chart, this is the current data that's being passed in to the chart:

```
var data = [{"date":"2012-03-20","total":3},{"date":"2012-04-21","total":8},{"date":"2012-05-22","total":2},{"date":"2012-06-23","total":10},
{"date":"2012-07-24","total":3},{"date":"2012-08-25","total":20},
{"date":"2012-09-26","total":12},{"date":"2012-10-23","total":10},
{"date":"2012-11-24","total":3},{"date":"2012-12-25","total":20},{"date":"2012-12-26","total":12}];
```

What i want to do is pass data attributes:

```
<div class="test">
  <div class"red" data-name"bar1" data-date="2012-03-20" data-total="6">
  </div>
  <div class="blue" data-name="bar2" data-date="2012-04-21" data-total="10">
 </div>

</div>
```

I want the dates and values to be obtained from "data-date" and "data-value". What relevant changes do i need to make to the "x" and "y" variable.

They are currently like so:

```
var x = d3.time.scale()
    .domain([new Date(data[0].date), d3.time.day.offset(new Date(data[data.length - 1].date), 1)])
    .rangeRound([0, width - margin.left - margin.right]);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.total+ (d.total/4); })])
```

Full code can be found here: https://jsfiddle.net/noobiecode/wck4ur9d/49/

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You want to parse the data out of those `div`s?  Or use those `div`s to represent bars?  I'm confused...

Comment: Sorry about the confusion. I want to parse the data out of those divs. So i want to use jquery to get the date and value of them bars. If that makes sense?

Comment: So i want to use jquery to get the date and value of them bars. For example, currently i'm creating bars using "data= []". What i want to do is create bars using the divs. I hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need for `jquery`, `d3` has it covered:

```
var data = [];
d3.selectAll(".test>div")
  .each(function() {
    var self = d3.select(this);
    data.push({
      date: self.attr("data-date"),
      total: +self.attr("data-value")
    });
  });
```

Updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wck4ur9d/50/).